# Domain of integration

Tags: calculus, integration, differential-geometry, manifolds

I am reading through Lee's *Introduction to smooth manifolds* and he defines a domain of integration to be a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ whose boundary has measure zero. He then goes on to say 'However, since we cannot guarantee that arbitrary open subsets or arbitrary compact subsets are domains of integration...'

I can see why an arbitrary open subset would not necessarily be a domain of integration (doesn't have to be bounded) - but how is it possible to have a compact set which is not a domain of integration? It is bounded and closed, and I'm trying to think of any compact set in, say, $\mathbb{R}^3$, I would think its boundary is 2 dimensional and thus has 3-dimensional measure zero?

Comment: The 3 dimensional analog of the Koch snowflake. The boundary of an $n$ dimensional set does not have to be $n-1$ dimensional.

Comment: There are Jordan curves with positive measure. By the Schoenflies theorem, they still bound a disc, so that's a compact 2-dimensional region with boundary of positive measure.